# Netbeans disabling code completion in HTML for quote marks

Tags: html, netbeans, autocomplete, netbeans7.0

In the Netbeans (v 7.01) code complete options I have disabled:

```
All Languages -> Insert Closing Brackets Automatically
Html -> Equals sign (=) Keypress After Attribute Name Autocompletes Quote Set
Html -> Quote mark (") Keypress After Attribute Name Autocompletes Closing Quote
```

and yet if I type out the following html line:

```
<div class = "">
```

Netbeans corrects this to:

```
<div class = """>
```

So in other words, the IDE adds in an extra quote mark. The problem doesn't seem to happen in PHP scripts, only HTML. But I'm finding it extremely infuriating and I can't figure out how to stop it!

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: What is your netbeans version ? This was a bug but fixed > 6.9.1

Comment: was it? I have version 7.0.1 but the problem is still occuring

Comment: See same question here in netbeans blog http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic32599.html with no answers !!!

Comment: hmm that's from a while ago too, maybe it's a bug. A terribly annoying one

Comment: looks like the netbeans link above may have been mis-pasted, it's nothing to do with code completion...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in NetBeans. Bug [224340 HTML auto-completion adds extra quote on properties](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=224340) was opened on it. Please update the bug with any additional comments.

**EDIT:**

Added a video on Vimeo demonstrating the behavior. [BUG#224340 NetBeans 7.2.1 HTML auto-completion adds extra quote on properties](https://vimeo.com/56559988)